# Is it allowed to submit accepted and published journal articles in Elsevier, to arXiv?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, arxiv, elsevier

As arXiv allows submitting research articles which helps in increasing its visibility. I was wondering if it is alright to submit accepted and published journal articles in Elsevier ([Expert Systems with Applications](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/expert-systems-with-applications/), [International Journal of Medical Informatics](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/journal/13865056)) to arXiv?

Comment: perhaps not a duplicate, but this question is relevant: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/62752/does-a-preprint-include-revisions-made-in-response-to-peer-review

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily find the answer following the author guidelines of Elsevier, starting from the link you provided. On https://www.elsevier.com/about/company-information/policies/sharing they explicitly state:

> Authors can update their preprints on arXiv or RePEc with their accepted manuscript .